# The proper control to use in WebForms for a stacked panel of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Learning `WebForms` here.  Usually code for `WinForms`.

I have a need to write a `stack panel` that accepts custom class as rows. In `Winforms` I would make a custom class inheriting `Panel` that would tell each new control added to its control collection the location.y and width.x and it should appear immediately under the previous control.

The type of incoming row controls would be of a number of other custom Panel classes, each with their own set of controls (buttons, drop downs. text, etc). That is, the incoming rows do not follow a consistent template (though the number or unique types for rows is only 2 or 3). The operation of the app would decided what type of row goes in next.

How would I do this in `WebForms`?

An example of a custom class derived from Panel and how to use it in markup might be all I need.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [ASP.NET AJAX Accordion control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Accordion/Accordion.aspx).